# Value of alpha and beta in Holt's exponential smoothing method

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, exponential-smoothing

How to choose the best values of alpha and beta in Holt's exponential smoothing? Leaving it upon R gives me $\alpha$ =1. Is this appropriate?

Entering different values of alpha and then comparing with the real data shows best result for $\alpha$ = 0.45. But then R calculates $\beta$=0.99. Is this fine?

Answer (score 6):

Values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ close to one suggest the model is mis-specified.

Try using the `ets()` function in the `forecast` package instead. It will choose the model for you, and select the best values of the smoothing parameters.

Comment: Used ets(). There is a slight improvement. Alpha=0.9999 while beta is close to 0.02. I am using daily data for one year for short-term forecasting. using six month data gives alpha=0.9996 with beta in the same range.

Comment: I think a value of alpha close to 1 means estimates are based on the recent observations while small beta implies that trend is not changing a lot. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in forecasting, but to my experience Holt-Winter's method may be highly unstable in R (especially in double exponential smoothing - where high frequency data may have extreme forecasts).

As for the alpha, beta values I think the most reasonable approach is to plot the forecasts--to  check whether the value given by R makes sense or not. As I said, factors such as missing values or high frequency may highly effect the output returned by R.

If you are using ggplot2, you might want to look to this [Plotting forecast() objects in ggplot part 2: Visualize Observations, Fits, and Forecasts](http://www.frankdavenport.com/blog/2012/3/21/plotting-forecast-objects-in-ggplot-part-2-visualize-observa.html).

Comment: I have plotted the data and it's constantly trending. Residuals have been checked. Only the value of alpha I get is 1. I thought it should be less than 1.